# Will I be penalised if my economics job market paper is coauthored with my supervisor?

Tags: phd, job-search, supervision

I read once before that the job market paper should not be coauthored with my supervisor because other universities will assume that my supervisor did all the work.

I will apply for an academic role after my PhD, is it true I will be penalised for this?

If my other two papers are relatively strong will that eliminate the risk?

But what if my supervisor coauthors on more than one paper?

Comment: Did you have a first author papers among these three?

Comment: I am not sure yet. Only 1 I think will be me as the sole author.

Comment: Which Field? In CS, I would expect the advisor to be the last author of all papers from his PhD candidates.. (Assuming that I correctly understood the question. It is quite confusing for me)

Comment: @FábioDias You should probably note that you mean applied CS (as it would be a very odd thing in theoretical CS where the authors are listed alphabetically).

Comment: @FábioDias That is wrong in general. There exist areas in CS, and advisors in CS who are not author (or last author) on all their students' papers.

Comment: @choener In my understanding, that would mean that the advisors didn't review the papers (or even guided the development), which is weird. Or is just common to disregard a contributing author?

Comment: @FábioDias Reviewing a paper is nowhere near enough to be included as an author. Nor is guiding the development of the paper in many cases.

Comment: In my case, my supervisor provided some of the data and guided the development. I guess that's why I include him, But I did all of the actual work. I think maybe it's just how it works.

Comment: What is a "job market paper"?

Comment: I write 3 papers, and I will decide which one is my job market paper. This paper is deemed the best of all 3 papers, and showcases the skills and ability of the student, as well as contributing to the field, and in most cases, will be the paper you submit for publishing. So when I apply for academic positions after my PhD, I will be judged primarily on my job market paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Economics is not my field, so my answer is based on what I've heard from other people. Generally, it is preferable if the job market paper has a sole authorship or at least if it is co-authored by other graduate students. However, I have heard of people getting jobs even with a job market paper coauthored with their advisor. Since you have two other papers, and one with sole authorship, that will to some extent work towards eliminating any negative impression that the job market paper may create. However, ultimately it will depend on your potential employers and the practices that they follow. Keep your fingers crossed and hope for the best.